# Remove "NaN" from HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's a stupid thing tho be honest. As you see in my fiddle, you can add and remove fields. The sum of the total of the amount inserted in the input fields works well.

But when I remove a field (which the total is 0), it changes to NaN.

Is it possible to make NaN == 0?

http://jsfiddle.net/1ggaco1d/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    /* --- ADD FIELD --- */
    rebind();

    $('.TotalMultiField').each(function () {
        var $wrapper = $('.multiFields', this);
        $(".addField", $(this)).click(function (e) {
            $('.multiField:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true)
                                .appendTo($wrapper)
                                .find('input')
                                .val('').focus();
            rebind();
        });

        /* --- REMOVE FIELD --- */

        $('.multiField .removeField', $wrapper).click(function () {

            if ($('.multiField', $wrapper).length > 1) {
                $(this).parent('.multiField').remove();
                total();
            }
        });

    });

});

function rebind() {
  $(".number").on('blur', function(e) { total(); })
}

function total() {

    var total = 0;
    $(".number").each(function (idx, el) {
        var value = $(el).val();
        if (value !== "") {
            total = total + parseFloat($(el).val());
        }

    });
    $("#added").text(total);
}
```

Comment: fiddle seems to work perfectly to me

Comment: Mmmmm sometimes there's some server errors...

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript isNaN() function.
like

```
if(isNaN(total) == ture)
{
  total = 0;
}
```